# OBIEE 12c. Color setting for pivot table

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, obiee

In OBIEE 12c there is a pivot table, built according to the format of a row with the attribute "Service", columns in the format "month" (from 1 to 12) -> "dedline_state" (not overdue / overdue) and the indicator "number of requests". Is it possible in OBIEE 12c to customize the colors exclusively for the "dedline_state" column with the "overdue" value; everything over 5% is highlighted in red?
[image]

That is, if you look at the example, then in 1 line 5 month the value "overdue" should be red.

Comment: you can try Conditional Format that you can set at the column you want to format

Comment: If I set a conditional format, then it will be applied immediately to all columns from the screenshot, since it is "not overdue"/ "overdue", these are not attributes, but values

Comment: Conditional Format is to format a column based on values of any column in the analysis